# How to display a fix part of website in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, html

I want to display a fix part of Website in Android using webview. This is the snapshot of webpage that have **Notices for the week** heading.

[image]

Now I want to display only this Notices for the week part in my webview like this :
[image]

Is this possible in android weview..?? I don't want to display anything else from website, only **Notices for the week** part.I don't have source code for this website. Please help me, I am not getting any idea how to do this..!!!

Comment: If the website provides a web-service then use it's API.

Comment: I am sending u link of site :
https://sites.google.com/site/holyfamilychurchpestomsagar/notices-for-the-week

Comment: You need to normally obtain the HTML each time and trim the parts you don't need then stick it in a webview

Comment: do u have any example for this..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other option, i.e. the website has no published rss feeds etc., You can use JSoup to parse the website and select any component of the website.

Jsoup is a Java Html parser which you can use to select DOM elements from a web/html page, provided it is properly formed.

Check out JSoup [here](http://jsoup.org/).